# Variable number of (const) reference arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to eliminate raw pointers from my high-level code (using C++11) and I found references (especially with `const`) to be a good replacement in many cases (when there is no ownership transfer).

But what to do if there is **variable** number of arguments that I'd like to pass by (const) reference?

You can't create an `std::vector` or `std::initializer_list` of references as these containers internally use the address of the stored elements but references don't have an address.

<strike>A possibility would be to use `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T>>` but that would require awkward client code like `doSomething({std::ref(A()), std::ref(B()), std::ref(C())})` instead of the nicer `doSomething({A(), B(), C()})` where `A`, `B` and `C` are classes derived from `T`.</strike>

Is it possible with some other container? Or maybe with variadic templates?

Comment: The goal isn't to eliminate raw pointers, the goal is to eliminate _owning_ raw pointers.  The usual tool for this task is `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 4):

Use a variadic template function to do this. There is certainly no need to pass a *container* of `T` to a function as a substitute for a variable argument list of `T`.

Here is an an example C++11 program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Base case with 0 arguments
std::vector<int> foo() {
    return std::vector<int>();
}

// General case with 1 + N arguments of type `int`.
// Return a `vector<int>` populated with the arguments. 
template<typename ...Args>
std::vector<int> foo(int const & first, Args const &... rest)
{
    std::vector<int> h(1,first);
    if (sizeof...(rest)) {
        std::vector<int> t = foo(rest...);
        h.insert(h.end(),t.begin(),t.end());
    }
    return h;

}

struct bar{};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 1, j = 2, k = 3;

    vector<int> v0 = foo(i,j);
    vector<int> v1 = foo(i,j,k);
    cout << v0.size() << endl;
    cout << v1.size() << endl;
    // bar b;
    // vector<int> v2 = foo(i,j,k,b); <-- Compile error  
    return 0;
}
```

At a glance, it may appear that the definition of `foo` in the general
case does not constraint all arguments to be (convertible to) `int`,
but in fact they must be - witness the uncompilable initialialization of
`v2`.

**Continued in response to OP's comments**

How to write a type-safe function taking variably many arguments of any given 
type, including const reference types, is not a problematic question in C++11.
The core language provides this syntactical pattern for doing it:

```
// Base case, 0 arguments
R Func() { [---] }

// General case, 1 + N arguments
template<typename U ...Args>
R Func(T [Modifier], Args [Modifier] ...args) {
    [---]
    if (sizeof...(args)) {
        [---Func(args)---]
    }
    [---]
}
```

where `[---]`, `[---Func(args)---]` may be filled-in.

The function template `foo` in the example program above applies this pattern.
You ask: *What if* `foo` *does something more complicated than just create a container?*
The answer is: You apply the pattern appropriately, whatever the complications
are - just as you would apply the pattern:

```
for( [---];[---];[---]) {
    [---]
}
```

appropriately, whatever the complications are. The variadic function template
pattern takes a bit more habituation because it involves recursive template
instantiation - that's all.

You appear to be confusing two things:

- A) A function that accepts a variable number of arguments of a type T.
- B) A function that accepts one argument of a type C, where C is an
  iterable sequence of objects of a type T.

In your own answer you say:

> The function that takes variable number of arguments can be written as:

```
void foo(std::initializer_list<rvalue_reference_wrapper<Base>> args)
{
    for (Base& arg : args)
    {
        arg.virtFunc();
        doStuffWithBaseRef(arg);
    }
}
```

That simply is *not* an A), it is a B).

Both here and in your comments you exhibit a wish to be able to *iterate over the
arguments* of a variadic function within the function body. In C/C++, there
is no mechanism to iterate over the arguments of a function, (unless it is
a [*varargs* function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Example_in_C) per Standard C) 
and you have not invented one. If a function is of type B), then obviously the 
function can iterate over the `T`s that are *members of* the `C` that is the argument of the function.
That is what you are doing in `foo` in your answer.

If it was impossible in C++ to code functions of type A) then as a kludge
we could substitute functions of type B). But functions of type A) are
routinely coded using the type-safe variadic template pattern shown and no such kludge
is called for. If what you want is a function of type A), use that pattern
and get the hang of it. If what you want is a function to iterate over the 
members of a sequence of `T`, then do as you have done: write one that takes an 
argument that is an iterable sequence of `T`.

Considered as a possible means for *passing an iterable sequence of [const]
references* to a function, your solution has the disabling limitation
that those references can only be references to temporary objects that *are
constructed in the initializer list*, not references to pre-existing objects
- as they almost always would be in real code. So for example, while the
code:

```
foo({Derived1(), Derived2()});
```

will compile and run as expected with the definitions of `foo`, `Derived1`,
`Derived2` in your answer, the vastly more likely case:

```
Derived1 d1; // <- Comes from somewhere
Derived2 d2; // <- Comes from somewhere
foo({d1,d2}); // <- Error
```

will not compile, because an lvalue `T` cannot bind to a `T&&`. To get around
this, you must write:

```
Derived1 d1; // <- Comes from somewhere
Derived2 d2; // <- Comes from somewhere
foo({Derived1(d1),Derived2(d2)});
```

so that now, you are constructing temporary *copies* of the "arguments", and
an `initalizer_list` of `rvalue_reference_wrapper`s of references to the
temporary copies, so that you can iterate over references to the temporaries within `foo`.

Well, if you have to use copies of the "arguments", it is superfluous
to bother with constructing a sequence of *references to the copies*. Just
copy the "arguments" into any suitable container and pass `foo` a [const] reference
to that. This won't stop `foo` from iterating over [const] references to the
container members just as it does now.

It seems likely that you are exercised in part by the question: *What
would be a suitable container for objects of varied types derived from a polymorphic
base* `B`*, if not a container of raw pointers to dynamically allocated objects?*

An uncontroversial answer to that is: `std::`*Container*`<std::shared_ptr<B>>`,
where *Container* is a Standard container template (vector,list, etc.) that
provides an appropriate interface to your application. More generally the so-called
*smart pointer* templates, `std::shared_ptr<T>`
([documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)) and
`std::unique_ptr<T>` ([documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr))
are the standard C++11 resources for avoiding exposure of raw dynamic pointers.

It seems likely also that you are attracted to `std::initializer_list` for
passing an iterable sequence to a function because of the ease with which you
can construct one at the point of use with a braced initializer. That convenience
can be retained without dealing in raw dynamic pointers *or* smart pointers.
E.g.

```
void foo(std::initializer_list<std::shared_ptr<Base>> args)
{
    for (auto arg : args)
    {
        arg->virtFunc();
        doStuffWithBaseRef(*arg);
    }
}

std::shared_ptr<Base> b1(new Derived1);
std::shared_ptr<Base> b2(new Derived2);
foo({b1,b2});
```

will be fine, and so will:

```
void foo(std::initializer_list<Base *> args)
{
    for (auto arg : args)
    {
        arg->virtFunc();
        doStuffWithBaseRef(*arg);
    }
}

Derived1 d1;
Derived2 d2;
foo({&d1,&d2});
```

Comment: What if `foo` does something more complicated than just create a container? For example iterate through the arguments in original order. Can I use `for_each` and a lambda on `rest`?
Also, could you comment on my answer (solution)?

Comment: I think the variadic template and the container passing solution is very similar (seen from the user perspective), so they have to be considered against each other. Variadic templates need template use (obviously) and a very twisted recursive way of expressing the algorithm. I would avoid using it throughout my classes if possible. The container passing version seems to be more flexible. I ended up using a std::vector<rvalue_reference_wrapper<T>> where rvalue_reference_wrapper has a T& as well as a T&& constructor.

Comment: I updated my answer with the version that I like the best now.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that works but it may not be the ideal solution.

The problem with `std::reference_wrapper` is that it can't be created from an rvalue reference. So I wrote my own `any_reference_wrapper` like this:

```
template<class T>
class any_reference_wrapper
{
public:
    any_reference_wrapper(T&& t) : ref(t) {}
    any_reference_wrapper(T& t) : ref(t) {}

    operator T&() const {return ref;}
    T& get() const {return ref;}
private:
    T& ref;
};
```

Then we can simplify our life by introducing

```
template<class T> using any_reference_initializer_list = 
    std::initializer_list<any_reference_wrapper<T>>;
```

The function that semantically takes variable number of arguments (but technically takes a container) can be written as:

```
void foo(any_reference_initializer_list<Base> args)
{
    for (Base& arg : args)
    {
        arg.virtFunc();
        doStuffWithBaseRef(arg);
    }
}
```

and can be called with temporaries like:

```
foo({Derived1(), Derived2()});
```

but also with references to already existing variables:

```
Derived d1;
foo({d1, Derived2()});
```

Advantages:

- `foo` does not have to be a template function (I like to avoid templates if possible).
- A simple for loop can be used in `foo`, no weird recursion which just confuses the reader.
- The caller doesn't have to provide smart pointers and the calling is very intuitive without any boilerplate.
- `foo` can have multiple such variable length lists of different types:

  ```
  void foo2(
      any_reference_initializer_list<SomeType1> args1,
      any_reference_initializer_list<SomeType2> args2);
  ```
- dynamic-length (runtime-decided) collections are also possible by a slight modification (using `std::vector` instead of `std::initializer_list`)

Used classes:

```
class Base 
{
    virtual void virtFunc() = 0;
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
    virtual void virtFunc()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived1" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
    virtual void virtFunc() 
    {
        std::cout << "Derived2" << std::endl;
    }
};

void doStuffWithBaseRef(Base& b)
{
    b.virtFunc();
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Mike Kinghan suggested that the use of `any_reference_wrapper` may lead to bugs that are hard to debug: If some function takes an `any_reference_wrapper` as a parameter and then goes on to treat it as if it were a standard `std::reference_wrapper` (not keeping in mind that it may be a wrapper around a temporary) then the program might crash when the temporary is already dead but some part of the program still keeps a reference to it.

My answer is that this is problem is not really unique to `any_reference_wrapper`. This can happen just as much in case of the implicit `T&&` to `const T&` conversion (as he also points out). But in that case, as he says, an explicit `void f(D const &&) = delete;` can save the day, disallowing temporaries as arguments. Okay. But we have an analogous solution for the case with `any_reference_wrapper`. Instead of using some `= delete` declaration we just don't overload the function to accept `any_reference_wrapper`. We only create a version that accepts standard `std::reference_wrapper`. That way we can be sure that we don't have to deal with temporaries.

Let me rephrase it. If you'd do explicit delete in the single-argument case (because the function does something that you should not do with temporaries, like storing the reference) then *simply do not define the overload* `void f(std::initializer_list<any_reference_wrapper<const T>>)`, only `void f(std::initializer_list<std::reference_wrapper<const T>>)` (note the `std::` in the latter). Only if your function is safe (meaning that you would allow the implicit `T&&` to `const T&` conversion if it were the single-argument case), only then should you define the `any_reference_wrapper` overload. The situation is totally analogous to the single-argument case, so it is not the least bit more bug-prone than the established standard behaviour of modern C++.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the update - there's a typo, at least. But the example in my answer #2 that provokes the pure-virtual-method-called
crash does it just the same regardless of whether you define `D const & pick_one(
std::initializer_list<any_reference_wrapper<D const>> args)` or `D & pick_one(std::initializer_list<any_reference_wrapper<D>> args)`
or indeed `D const & pick_one(std::initializer_list<any_reference_wrapper<D>> args)`

Comment: I'm comparing the case of having as parameter `std::initializer_list<any_reference_wrapper<D>> args` vs. `std::initializer_list<std::reference_wrapper<D>> args` (any_reference_wrapper vs std::reference_wrapper). If you take the any_ version, then you must treat them as potential temporaries, just like you would if you wrote a `foo(D const&)`. In a `foo(D const&)` you cannot assume that you have an lvalue ref. Only if you explicitly `delete` the rvalue overload. But this solution also works with the wrappers: define only the overload with std::reference_wrapper. I hope it's clearer what I mean.

Comment: You'd need this caveat in your docs, so when we use your template when we shouldn't and crash like that you can say: RTFM man - if you'd used the *Standard Library* there, you couldn't have compiled that bug at all! Anyway, I don't spurn variadic template functions, esp. if it's that or non-standard template library. I prefer `foo(a,b,c)` to `f({a,b,c})`, and all I'll get for the extra braces and the dangerous non-standard reference wrapper is slower code, so I'm afraid I'm not sold :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than balloon my first answer again, here's another one.

I applaud your having programmer-like ideas and not settling for "This is how
it's done" to dislodge them.

In your new solution, `any_reference_wrapper<T>` is roughly a merging
of `std::reference_wrapper<T>` with your previous `rvalue_reference_wrapper<T>`.

In that light, I'll take up an issue with `rvalue_reference_wrapper<T>` that
I didn't pursue before, that is equally an issue for `any_reference_wrapper<T>`
and which springs from the key difference between `rvalue_reference_wrapper<T>` and
`std::reference_wrapper<T>`.

That key difference, of course, is that an `std::reference_wrapper<T>` 
cannot bind its wrapped reference to temporary, a limitation that you
disliked because it would call for 
"awkward client code like `doSomething({std::ref(A()), std::ref(B()), std::ref(C())})`".

Actually, such client code would not merely be awkward, it would not compile.
Try:

```
#include <functional>
struct X{};

int main()
{
    X & rx = std::ref(X());
    return 0;
}
```

and you will see a diagnostic like:

> error: use of deleted function 'void std::ref(const _Tp&&) [with _Tp = X]'

The [documentation of `std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref)
confirms that the authors of the Standard Library have chosen to expressly 
delete `std::ref(const T&&)`. They were bound to make that choice, since
they have also chosen to expressly delete the [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/reference_wrapper)
`std::reference_wrapper(T&&)` - the one you brought back for
`rvalue_reference_wrapper<T>` and have kept in `any_reference_wrapper<T>`.
You are devising something that is not merely missing from the
Standard Library but signposted *Don't Do This* in the Standard Library.
And you are devising it for a purpose that the core language already fulfils.

In those choices, the authors of the library are upholding the universally
approved principle that binding temporary objects to references is
foolhardy. It can be done and can happen safely within narrow constraints,
but writing classes *with the purpose* of perpetrating it is
deplorable.

Binding temporaries to references is foolhardy because the reference can
so easily continue in use after the temporary to which was bound is deceased.

So if your `any_reference_wrapper<T>` (or your `rvalue_reference_wrapper<T>`)
were ever to infilitrate the library of a real production codeline, uses
essentially like the following program would arise, but in some more
complex and obscure way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>       

template<class T>
class any_reference_wrapper
{
public:
    any_reference_wrapper(T && t) : ref(t) {}
    any_reference_wrapper(T & t) : ref(t) {}

    operator T &() const  {return ref;}
    T & get() const {return ref;}
private:
    T  & ref;
};

struct B 
{
    virtual void virt() const = 0;
    virtual ~B() {
        std::cout << "~B()" <<std::endl;
    }
};

struct D : public B
{
    D(){}
    void virt() const override
    {
        std::cout << "D::virt()" << std::endl;
    }
    ~D() override {
        std::cout << "~D()" <<std::endl;
    }

};

D const & pick_one(
        std::initializer_list<any_reference_wrapper<D const>> args) {
    return *args.begin(); // <- Whatever
}

int main()
{
    D d1, d2; // <- From somewhere
    D const & rb = pick_one({d1,d2});
    rb.virt();
    return 0;
}
```

Which is all perfectly fine! Output:

```
D::virt()
~D()
~B()
~D()
~B()
```

And almost identical uses would accrue, essentially as represented by changing the
first two lines in `main` to:

```
D d1; // <- From somewhere
D const & rb = pick_one({D(),d1});
```

but in some more complex and obscure way.

Now the output is:

```
~D()
~B()
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted
```

Many professional C++ programmers would be mystified as to what
kind of bug could possibly cause a `pure virtual method called` crash from a
virtual method call on a reference to a type, `D`, *that has no pure virtual
methods*, and could tired and emotional by the time they tracked it down. In this example, fortunately, the destructor tracing is a strong clue: It's what you are likely to get for making a virtual method call through a reference bound a temporary that has already been destroyed.

True, exactly the same vulnerability can be demonstrated with:

```
D const & f(D const & d) {
    return d;
}
D const & rb = f(D());
rb.virt();
```

with `any_reference_wrapper<T>` nowhere in sight. *But I can close that
vulnerability with:*

```
void f(D const &&) = delete;
```

in the same way that Standard Library closes it with:

```
std::reference_wrapper( T&& x ) = delete;
void std::ref(const T&&) = delete;
```

On the other hand, it is clear at a glance that `any_reference_wrapper<T>`
is *designed to have* this vulnerability, and for that reason it would not be 
allowed to infilitrate the library of any production codeline in competent hands.

Now as long as you don't insist on binding temporaries to the `arg`s in
the `foo({arg,[arg,...]}` simulated variadic function idiom that you favour,
`std::reference_wrapper<T>` will serve your stated goal of avoiding the
*weird* and *confusing* variadic function template idiom that is native to
the language, and your client coders will be free to write function calls like 
`foo({a,b,c})` where the conventional variadic function idiom would force
them to write `foo(a,b,c)`.

But appreciate that the variadic template apparatus is core to the
unparalleled expressive power of modern C++, and that all uses
of that apparatus involve the *weird* and *confusing* application of
compiletime recursion. When C++ first went mainstream - before templates
- the apparatus of polymorphism was deemed so weird and confusing by
some C programmers that they started inventing ways by which classes could
be sort-of simulated in C. Later when C++ acquired templates, they bewildered some 
people so much that they preferred to sort-of simulate templates with preprocessor 
macros. Variadic templates and compiletime recursion are the new normal and have
been so for several years. If you prefer to devise ways to sort-of simulate them
without using them you are just going to write oddball code. Better to use your brains 
to keep learning rather than to avoid learning.

The variadic template apparatus is also core to the unparalleled performance
of modern C++. You could make experimental program like this:

Write a polymorphic base class `B` with the pure virtual member:

```
virtual int B::value() const = 0;
```

Write a concrete class `D`(or more than one) derived from `B`

Generate some sequence `S` of derived objects by means of your choice.

Define the conventional variadic function template:

```
int variadic() {
    return 0;
}

template<class ...T>
int variadic(B const & first, T const &... rest) {
    int i = first.value();
    if (sizeof...(rest)) {
        i += variadic(rest...);
    }
    return i;
}
```

Define the pseudo-variadic function:

```
int pseudo_variadic(std::initializer_list<std::reference_wrapper<B const>> args)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (B const & arg : args) {
        i += arg.value();
    }
    return i;
}
```

So here you have a variadic function and a pseudo-variadic function that
use all of their arguments, implementing the same algorithm. In each case,
that involves iterating over the arguments from first to last. For `variadic`,
the iteration is done recursively *in compiletime*. For `pseudo_variadic`
it is done loop-wise *in runtime*.

Call each function, say, a million times in a loop, passing each the arguments
in `S` in the appropriate fashion, and making sure the results of the calls 
must be used by the program.

Time each of the loops with `clock()` and compare. With `-O2` optimization
using gcc 4.9, I find that `variadic` executes on average 4.3 times faster
than `pseudo_variadic`. Which is not suprising, since `pseudo_variadic`
represents a way of using C++ to implement variadic functions in essentially
the way of perl or python.

Answer (score 0):

You could use these macros

```
typedef int INT_ARRAY[];
#define BEGIN_FOR_EACH_VARIADIC(ArgT,ArgV,param) INT_ARRAY{([&](ArgT param)
#define END_FOR_EACH_VARIADIC(ArgT,ArgV) (std::forward<ArgT>(ArgV)),0)...,0};
```

and then use variadic templates:

```
template <class...Ts>
void do_foo(Ts...Args) {
   BEGIN_FOR_EACH_VARIADIC(Ts,Args,param) 
   {
       param.virtFunc();
       doStuffWithBaseRef(param);
   }
   END_FOR_EACH_VARIADIC(Ts,Args)
}
```

Pretty straightforward.  If you want to enforce that a specific type is passed, just use a wrapper.

```
template<class...Ts>
void foo(Ts...Args) 
{return do_foo(((const Base&)Args)...);}
```

Comment: First, macros are ugly. Also, in this solution the parameter list of `foo` gives no clue about the the type of refereces that can be passed in (in this case int).

Comment: @qorilla: Why do you say "in this case, int"?  Neither your code nor my code targets `int`.  Oh, you're confused by the `int` in my typedef?  No, that's just part of the magic that makes the `FOR_EACH` work.  This concept works with any types, even completely unrelated types.  If you want to enforce a type though... I'll edit

Comment: @qorilla: And macros _are_ ugly, but in certain cases, (like this one), the code without the macros is far uglier.

Comment: Templates have all kinds of problems. For example the function signature doesn't show the expected type so the IDE can not tell me that `foo` wants `const Base&` arguments.

Something like `void foo(const Base&... args)` would be nicer but I know that it doesn't work that way.