# C++11 passing variadic number of objects by reference to function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass a variable number of objects by reference in C++11.

The C-style of variadic argumnets did not seem very elegant, so I tried using the std::initialiszer_list.

But all the examples i found used pass by copy, I wrote a simple example of what I want to achieve:

```
//Example class for illustration purposes
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    : m_id(0), m_idChecks(0)
    {}
    ~MyClass(){}

    int getId()
    {
        m_idChecks++;
        return m_id;
    }
    int getIdChecks() const
    {
        return m_idChecks;
    }

private:
    int m_id;
    int m_idChecks;
};


// I want to do something like this (pass the objects by reference):
// void test_initializerList(std::initializer_list<MyClass&> listClasses) 
// But only pass by copy works:
void test_initializerList(std::initializer_list<MyClass> listClasses) 
{
    // Doing operations on copies of the object:
    int sum = 0;
    for(auto c : listClasses)
    {
        sum += c.getId();
    }
    std::cout << "\n id: " << sum;
}
void test()
{

    MyClass c1;
    MyClass c2;
    MyClass c3;

    test_initializerList({c1,c2,c3});
    std::cout << "\n Wanted: " << 1 << " id checks, got: " << c1.getIdChecks() << "\n";
}
```

So how do you pass a variable number of arguments in modern C++? Examples are appreciated!

Comment: One could use [*parameter packs*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude iterating through parameter pack, though, is not nice :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable number of (const) reference arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613363/variable-number-of-const-reference-arguments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `initializer_list` can only copy it's arguments, and can't hold a reference to it (directly at least). However, there is way around it (example trimmed):

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

//Example class for illustration purposes
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() : m_idChecks(0) {}
    ~MyClass(){}

    int getId() const
    {
        return m_idChecks++;
    }
    int getIdChecks() const
    {
        return m_idChecks;
    }

private:
    mutable int m_idChecks;
};


using r = std::reference_wrapper<MyClass>;
void test_initializerList(std::initializer_list<r> listClasses) 
{
    // Doing operations on copies of the object:
    int sum = 0;
    for(const auto& c : listClasses)
    {
        sum += c.get().getId();
    }
}
int main()
{

    MyClass c1;
    MyClass c2;
    MyClass c3;

    test_initializerList({c1,c2,c3});
    std::cout << "\n Wanted: " << 1 << " id checks, got: " << c1.getIdChecks() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: It is worth noting that the copies do not occur when the arguments are passed to the function (a `std::initializer_list` is actually a "reference"), but at the call site where the `std::initializer_list` is created.

Comment: Thanks @sergeyA, this code is much easier to understand than parameter pack which was also very hard to get to work for my real case. The next person that reads the code has a far higher chance of understanding it... (although they shouldnt have to re-read it ever).